# Excluding specific multiple tags in the tag list in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

I want to exclude 2 tags from the tag list in the following script:

```
$tags = get_tags();
$html = '<ul>';
foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
if($tag->slug != "test1"){
$tag_link = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );
$html .= "<li><a href='{$tag_link}' class='{$tag->slug}'>";
$html .= "{$tag->name}</a></li>";
}}
$html .= '</ul>';
echo $html;
```

The script works correctly excluding `test1` tag. 
How do I edit the code in order to also exclude another tag named `test2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [**DOCS**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags):

> '**exclude**' Default is an empty string. A comma- or space-delimited
>   string of term ids to exclude from the return array. If 'include' is
>   non-empty, 'exclude' is ignored.

You need to change `1,2` with tag ids of `test1` & `test2`.

```
$args = array('exclude' => '1,2' );
$tags = get_tags($args);
// .... Rest of your code goes here
```

Don't forget to remove if check `if($tag->slug != "test1"){` as it would be useless with `exclude` in `$args` :)

Comment: Don't forget to then leave the if($tag->slug != "test1"){ part out because it is not needed anymore